# Struts 2 GAE No action mapped for namespace [/]

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, struts2, namespaces, action-mapping

I'm learning Struts 2 for a project requirement and I've met some issues.

Following this tutorial at:

http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-struts-2-example/

And what I've done extra:

- Added an index.jsp into the war folder
- Changed web.xml to

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">
      <filter>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

      <listener>
          <listener-class>com.mkyong.listener.Struts2ListenerOnGAE</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
  ```

Now, when I rebuild and loads

```
    http://localhost:8888
```

Rather then seeing the content I should have in my index.jsp, I'm getting a

```
    Error 404 There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [].
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? I've seen some other similar questions in SO but their solutions do not work for this specific example of Struts 2 + GAE.

My struts.xml

```
    <struts>
        <package name="user" namespace="/User" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="Login">
                <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="Welcome" class="com.mkyong.user.action.WelcomeUserAction">
                <result name="SUCCESS">pages/welcome_user.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

**Folder structure**

I cant post images so, http://i.imgur.com/KSPmaMr.png

**Exact same libraries used for download**

http://www[dot]mediafire[dot]com/?utliwvcmo63o8l7

Comment: I guess ,you have not mapped the action-name in your struts.xml file, please show me your struts.xml file.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk Hi, as per the tutorial, there wasnt a need for a struts mapping to index.html no? Sorry new to this.

Comment: I guess you have deleted everything from `web.xml` file, above is the only content in web.xml now as I can't see the mapping to `filterdispatcher` that actually looks for struts.xml file.

Comment: ok,is your struts.xml file is in your root directory, i mean where you have placed your struts.xml file?

Comment: I know ,there is no need of action_mapping for index.jsp but if you have copy-pasted the code ,then you need to mapped all the action which is resides in your view

Comment: @pKs , I have included the entire file.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk , however, I can load index.html just fine and I see everything, even the Action classes are working fine with all the linkages. Is there anything else I need to add/change?

Comment: if all is working fine, then what is your problem ,tell me specifically, and where you put your struts.xml file

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk , struts.xml file is in my root src folder. The problem is I want to change index.html to index.jsp but simply including the index.jsp in the same folder as index.html currently and changing the welcome-file to index.jsp cause that error I've stated.

Comment: @Eleazar Have you resolved the issue , I guess you should first understand how exactly the flow between these files work or how actually the struts2 framework works.

Comment: @pKs I have not unfortunately. I come from a struts 1 background and trying to understand struts 2 by examples.

Comment: @Eleazar `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` have you specified the taglib in your `index.jsp` :)

Answer (score 1):

ok ,i got your problem,

change your struts.xml to this

```
  <struts>
       <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
            <action name="Login">
                <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="Welcome" class="com.mkyong.user.action.WelcomeUserAction">
                <result name="SUCCESS">pages/welcome_user.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

I  guess this will work, because **filterDispatcher** search for **struts.xml** file in root folder if you put your struts.xml file in root directory.

Comment: I have changed it but it does not work. From what i can tell, you changed the package name from user to default? I'm trying to make pointing to index.jsp in the welcome-file work though.

struts.xml is in my root /src folder

Comment: ok, your url http://localhost:8888, why this is showing your portname only this should be like this http://localhost:8888/your-project-name

Comment: Yes I can load http://xxxx.com/index.jsp fine with no problems. But I'm trying to make index.jsp load when I enter http://xxxx.com 

which in this case is the localhost:8888

I dont want my users to go to http://xxxx.com/projectname 

I feel it is excessive when they can just go to xxxx.com

Comment: you have just missed the point, if you run your project on localhost using ide then the should be like this localhost:8888/your-project-name

Comment: Sorry I have missed that. However, the project name is Struts2GoogleAppEngine. And loading, http://localhost:8888/Struts2GoogleAppEngine also gives the same error.

Comment: I have added the folder structure image to the first post.

Answer (score 1):

@Eleazar I followed the mykong tutorial link that you mentioned in your question. There is no use of `index.html` as far as I see that tutorial. `<welcome-list>` file is used when the is no action mentioned on application startup.

On *step:8* in that tutorial they has provided the `url` which is `http://localhost:8888/User/Login.action` you need to run the test. Its got nothing to do with file in welcome list...

**UPDATE:**

You are getting that error because you have added struts2 filter as `/*`, and your action namespace is for `/User`. There is not action namespace for `/`. Adding package with name="default" with namespace="/" i.e `<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/"></package>` will resolve you issue. It will hit `<welcome-file>`

Comment: Yes I understand where you're coming from. However, I would like to include an index.jsp as the 'landing' page for wherever i'm trying to deploy. which in this case, it is localhost:8888

I want localhost:8888, or when i deploy on websites, to have their root point to my index.jsp first. This is what i'm trying to make happen but its not allowing me to.

Comment: ok then do this define another package in struts.xml i.e `<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/"></package>` before your package with name user. Dont write any actions in it. Keep index.jsp in web-content folder. And run app. hope you see you index.jsp page

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just tried this too and the error still comes up. ):

Comment: Eleazar did you followed the article exactly ? Do you have THE SAME versions of all the libraries of the article ? If you call http://localhost:8888/User/Login.action it is not possible you get errors for "/" namespace anymore, you will be on /User namespace...

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes Andrea, you are right. But that is not the problem. I can reach Login.action just fine. The problem is i'm trying to reach a index.jsp at the main domain like http://localhost:8888/ when the default is a index.html

I used exactly the same versions of those libraries stated in the tutorial. I will attach a zip of all the libraries used in the first post. And yes, I followed all the steps closely. If you try it out, i'm sure you will hit the same error. 

I'm on eclipse IDE juno.

Comment: Its clearly a problem of namespace... my suggestion should work :(

Comment: Can you try it out too and see if you get the error? I have attached the files needed. Source code is also on the website. ):

Comment: @Eleazar I have got busy with important work, will try as soon as I get free coz I need to download GAE SDK for that.. need some more time:P